# macOS Terminal, Connect to SSH using Socks Proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks, socks5

I have been using this command to connect Terminal to my local SOCKS5 Proxy:

```bash
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8070 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8070 && curl ifconfig.me;
```

My IP is correct according to [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me), so port 80 and 443 work fine, but when I use SSH, I'm not connected through the proxy.

Is there a simple way around that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to connect ssh via shadowsocks with netcat:

```
 ssh -v -o 'ProxyCommand=ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1086 %h %p' -p22 username@ip
```

You can add it to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
     ProxyCommand=ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1086 %h %p
```

netcat isnt avaliable in MacOS by default, you need to install:

```
brew install nmap
```

Answer (score 3):

One can also use `nc` which is now included in MacOS. On the command line:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand=/usr/bin/nc -x socks_proxy:1080 -W %h:%p " ssh_host
```

Or in the `~/.ssh/config` file (change the `Host` entry to suit your needs) e.g To use the proxy all hosts:

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -x socks_proxy:1080 %h %p
```

Then you can just connect using:

```
ssh ssh_host
```